# wice_grid grid locks after first filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wice-grid

I am using wice_grid and trying to get filtering to work.

```
#[controller].rb
def queue
  @grid = initialize_grid(Indication)
end

#view
<%= grid(@grid) do |g|
g.column name: "id", attribute: "id" do |t|
t.id
end
end %>
```

Together, these make the table I want (I stripped down my original table to these bare bones and I have the same issue).

I can enter a value into the sorting field and click on the Y-shaped filter icon.  Filtering appears to work correctly.  However, after this, I can no longer change my filter (I can change the value in the box, but clicking on the filter icon again appears to do nothing), nor can I restore the full table by clicking on the grid icon.

If I reload the page, the value in the filter field reverts to whatever value was inputted the first time (as expected).  I can actually run another filter/restore table, but after this action is taken, the grid appears to be locked again.

Any ideas what to do?  Could this be a Javascript issue?

Comment: I'm noticing on http://wicegrid.herokuapp.com, on selecting a filter, the page does reload.  This is not happening for me.  I think this is promising, but I don't know what to do with this information.

Comment: I tried deattching the filters, but the same result

Answer (score 1):

I feel dumb.  RTFM!!!!

Needed to include `jquery-ui` in my javascript file.